# Maven: NoClassDefFoundError of system scoped dependency

Tags: java, android, maven

I am developing an **Android** project with Maven. I have a third-party jar file that I have included in a `lib` folder on my project root directory:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.parse</groupId>
     <artifactId>parse</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.2</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${project.basedir}\lib\Parse-1.9.2.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

But when I install the apk in my phone, I get `NoClassDefFoundError`. Obviously, that class exists inside the jar.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: change the scope into provided and test it again

Comment: Build error: `'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.parse:parse:jar must be omitted. This field may only be specified for a dependency with system scope`

Comment: You also need to remove the <systemPath> tag and load the jar into your local maven repo.

Comment: please check compile instead of system too and see what happen

Comment: @DSF yes, I think I will try to install the jar into my repo, instead of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using one of your directories as a repository, add your jar in it, and load it the proper Maven way.

You can do this adding this to your pom.xml and putting your jar in /lib:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>mylibid</id>
       <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>

...

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.parse</groupId>
      <artifactId>parse</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add my two cents here, [you can install the third-party into your local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) firstly and try add dependency directly.

Take your scenario as an example. Change to the folder where contains the third jar and type:

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.parse -DartifactId=parse -Dversion=1.9.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=Parse-1.9.2.jar`

Modify your `pom.xml` to add the dependency.

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.parse</groupId>
      <artifactId>parse</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```